# How to get Apache Camel Docker component to work in OSGi? or (Jersey does not work in OSGi)

Tags: jersey, apache-camel, osgi, jersey-2.0

It appears that the Apache Camel Docker component does not work in OSGI.

I get the following error message which appears to be caused by Jersey not working in the OSGi environment. Outside of the OSGi environment it works fine.

The key error message is here:

*java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Provider org.glass
fish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl could not be instantiated: java.lang.Il
legalStateException: No generator was provided and there is no default generator
 registered*

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Provider org.glass
fish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl could not be instantiated: java.lang.Il
legalStateException: No generator was provided and there is no default generator
 registered
        at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:152
)
        at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.getInstance(RuntimeDelegate.java:120)

        at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.newInstance(UriBuilder.java:95)
        at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:106)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.<init>(JerseyWebTarget.ja
va:81)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient.target(JerseyClient.java:297
)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient.target(JerseyClient.java:76)

        at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.DockerCmdExecFactoryImpl.init(DockerCmdEx
ecFactoryImpl.java:114)
        at com.github.dockerjava.core.DockerClientImpl.withDockerCmdExecFactory(
DockerClientImpl.java:60)
        at com.github.dockerjava.core.DockerClientBuilder.build(DockerClientBuil
der.java:61)
        at org.apache.camel.component.docker.DockerClientFactory.getDockerClient
(DockerClientFactory.java:118)
        at org.apache.camel.component.docker.producer.DockerProducer.process(Doc
kerProducer.java:99)
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncP
rocessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:1
45)
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(Instrume
ntationProcessor.java:77)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(Trace
Interceptor.java:163)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryE
rrorHandler.java:468)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelIntern
alProcessor.java:197)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:121)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelIntern
alProcessor.java:197)
        at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer.sendTimerExchange(Time
rConsumer.java:192)
        at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer$1.run(TimerConsumer.ja
va:76)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Provider org.glassfish.jersey.inter
nal.RuntimeDelegateImpl could not be instantiated: java.lang.IllegalStateExcepti
on: No generator was provided and there is no default generator registered
        at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:122)
        at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:225)
        at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:135
)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No generator was provided and there
is no default generator registered
        at org.glassfish.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.internalCreate(S
erviceLocatorFactoryImpl.java:308)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.create(ServiceLo
catorFactoryImpl.java:293)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections._createLocator(Inject
ions.java:138)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createLocator(Injecti
ons.java:109)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl.<init>(RuntimeDeleg
ateImpl.java:63)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstruct
orAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC
onstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
        at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:118)
        ... 26 more
[Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - timer://fetch] WARN org.apache.camel.component.time
r.TimerConsumer - Error processing exchange. Exchange[ID-orsa-52510-147330437161
1-0-2]. Caused by: [java.lang.RuntimeException - java.lang.ClassNotFoundExceptio
n: Provider org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl could not be insta
ntiated: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No generator was provided and there is
 no default generator registered]
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Provider org.glass
fish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl could not be instantiated: java.lang.Il
legalStateException: No generator was provided and there is no default generator
 registered
        at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:152
)
        at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.getInstance(RuntimeDelegate.java:120)

        at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.newInstance(UriBuilder.java:95)
        at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:106)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.<init>(JerseyWebTarget.ja
va:81)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient.target(JerseyClient.java:297
)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient.target(JerseyClient.java:76)

        at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.DockerCmdExecFactoryImpl.init(DockerCmdEx
ecFactoryImpl.java:114)
        at com.github.dockerjava.core.DockerClientImpl.withDockerCmdExecFactory(
DockerClientImpl.java:60)
        at com.github.dockerjava.core.DockerClientBuilder.build(DockerClientBuil
der.java:61)
        at org.apache.camel.component.docker.DockerClientFactory.getDockerClient
(DockerClientFactory.java:118)
        at org.apache.camel.component.docker.producer.DockerProducer.process(Doc
kerProducer.java:99)
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncP
rocessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:1
45)
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(Instrume
ntationProcessor.java:77)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(Trace
Interceptor.java:163)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryE
rrorHandler.java:468)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelIntern
alProcessor.java:197)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:121)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelIntern
alProcessor.java:197)
        at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer.sendTimerExchange(Time
rConsumer.java:192)
        at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer$1.run(TimerConsumer.ja
va:76)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Provider org.glassfish.jersey.inter
nal.RuntimeDelegateImpl could not be instantiated: java.lang.IllegalStateExcepti
on: No generator was provided and there is no default generator registered
        at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:122)
        at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:225)
        at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:135
)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No generator was provided and there
is no default generator registered
        at org.glassfish.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.internalCreate(S
erviceLocatorFactoryImpl.java:308)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorFactoryImpl.create(ServiceLo
catorFactoryImpl.java:293)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections._createLocator(Inject
ions.java:138)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.createLocator(Injecti
ons.java:109)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl.<init>(RuntimeDeleg
ateImpl.java:63)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstruct
orAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC
onstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
        at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:118)
        ... 26 more
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? ^C

C:\home\projects\universe\browser\application\apps\JumpMicro\core>
```

Comment: You should post a bug request on https://issues.apache.org/jira

Comment: I can't work out how to post a bug request, its so complicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An answer which works is if I run this at start of program:

```
RuntimeDelegate.setInstance(new org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl())
```

However, I don't think I should need to do this.